# Lineage OS 14.1; Missing TWRP and 7GB of storage

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, lineageos

Yesterday I installed Lineage OS 14.1 + GApps on my Galaxy S2 using one video from youtube.

Links to necessary files were there, so I just downloaded:

- odin3 v1.85
- lp-kernel-14-03-CWM-for+ODIN.tar
- lineage-14.1-20180301-nightly-i9100-signed.zip
- open_gapps-arm-7.1-pico-20180306.zip
- PIT1GBsystem3gb4gb6gb8gbDATA.zip (I used I91001GB_3GB.pit as it was recommended in video)
- recovery-Lanchon-IsoRec-TWRP-2.8.7.0-20160113-i9100-(by-arnab).zip

After installing I went to storage settings and see only one partition of 4GB size available. On the stock ROM there were 11GB of space on sdcard0 (internal storage).

There is no option to format internal storage.

ES File Explorer cannot access the / directory.

How to have 11GB again and access to root partition?

Additionally I looked how to install Root. All the instructions lead to booting in TWRP. But my Lineage OS14.1 has no TWRP recovery, and the standard recovery refuses to install root update (addonsu-14.1-arm-signed.zip). How to root the phone?

Comment: The pit supposedly takes space from your internal storage partition to compensate for the lack of `/system` and `/data` space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!

As instructed I flashed lp-kernel-14-03-CWM-for+ODIN.tar and using it's recovery installed then lineage-14.1-20180301-nightly-i9100-signed.zip and open_gapps-arm-7.1-pico-20180306.zip and that was all.

What I should do else is to install recovery-Lanchon-IsoRec-TWRP-2.8.7.0-20160113-i9100-(by-arnab).zip and addonsu-14.1-arm-signed.zip as long as custom recovery works, because after reboot it will be too late.

Now I have root and TWRP and will check what is up with big internal memory.